# Set up interface in Interface Builder and reuse it in for loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

Ok, I'm a bit new to iOS programming, and I'm not too sure how to phrase the question but hopefully someone could point me in the right direction.
I'm trying to create something like a news app. The interface would be entirely large image tiles, some larger, some smaller, with a title over each image. Now is it sensible to create a couple of those tiles with images and titles in interface builder and then in the app just loop them for a couple of times for every category that i have in my JSON array.

For example I'd have 3 tiles for 'Sports', then 3 tiles for 'Politics' etc etc.

Is this accaptable way of doing things or should I do everything programmaticaly?

Thanks for any help, hopefully the question made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly. But you can create different views in some NIB files (eg. sports.xib, politics.xib) and instantiate a view-controller with this or that nib depending on your needs:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"sports" bundle:nil];
```

or

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"politics" bundel: nil];
```

Comment: I was thinking to create something that resembles a Windows Phone kind of layout with large and small tiles in storyboard and just repeat that layout in a loop because the layout would be the same, only the images and titles would be different.